# Simchas Torah dancing prior to finishing the Torah

Tags: siyum, simchat-torah, dance

To the best of my knowledge, the Minhag by all on Simchas Torah is to first have Hakafos, and then complete the Torah. By a Siyum the general rule is to first complete the Siyum and then to start dancing. Why the difference between Simchas Torah and a regular Siyum? Is there a reason why one is different than the other? (looking for a sourced or a logical answer)

Comment: Nice question. FYI, many shuls that I have seen actually read and complete the Torah first, daven Musaf, and have hakafot after all davening has completed. I'm not sure what their reason for doing this is (I said, "many", not a majority). Perhaps, it's because of what you just mentioned?

Comment: What makes you say the Hakafos are dancing for the Siyum?

Comment: @DanF: I have never seen that done. It would be interesting to know if that is their reason, or if it is done for other reasons, such as better timing for wife and kids to come, etc.

Comment: Perhaps, because unlike a typical siyum Gemara, where we just finish a masechta, and that's it, on Simchat Torah, we don't actually "finish", we restart with Breishit immediately? Maybe that's the main difference? Also, see DoubleAA's query.

Comment: @GershonGold - Not sure. It may be partially for what you stated. Perhaps, it's b/c they're more concerned about getting to the schnapps, cake and kugel more quickly.

Comment: @DanF A Siyum Gemara also involves starting something else after.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Not "typical" in any siyum that I have been to. I should attend some of yours. Just make sure that it has moist marble cake ;-)

Comment: @DoubleAA: Perhaps there is another reason that we do Hakafos on Simchas Torah. I for one never heard another reason.

Comment: @GershonGold It's an honorary procession to the Bimah for the Siyum. Like an honorary procession to the Chuppah at a wedding or [to receive an award](https://youtu.be/yixG8pfncOs?t=13). Hakafot aren't a celebration. Why is walking in a circle 7 times celebratory?

Comment: @DoubleAA: It sounds like you have a logical answer.

Comment: Interestingly, by the Simchas Beis Hasho'eiva they would also dance before doing the _mitzvah_ (the drawing of the water).

Answer (score 3):

See [p. 180 in this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=xU8eAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA180&lpg=PA180&dq=reason%20for%20hakafot%20on%20simchat%20torah&source=bl&ots=cubh5KpE-j&sig=GFJQ3nbGDx-SDdhvfTD4kjC8jxQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4Kw2VZupE5CTyATKpYHYCQ&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=reason%20for%20hakafot%20on%20simchat%20torah&f=false). Hakafot on SImchat Torah was a relatively late addition done in the 16th century. One of the reasons mentioned in the source is that it is actually a supplication and extension of the prayer for rain. That is why we say *Ana Hashem Hoshi'ah Na*.

Reason #2 on that page notes that the Hakafot use one of the last phrases in *Halel*. I am surmising that because of this concept, the *Hakafot* were positioned closer to Halel.

Regardless, it does not appear that Hakafot have any connection to it being or resembling a *siyum*. If anything, perhaps, the Kiddush after you get the aliyah is closer to the siyum :-o